# convert an object to multiple objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want convert an object to multiple objects in javascript.

this is my object:

```
const obj =  jQuery('.sts_create form').serializeArray();
```

`console.log` logs this:

```
1
: 
{name: 'target_tag', value: 'a'}
2
: 
{name: 'animation_status', value: 'animation-1'}
3
: 
{name: 'duration', value: ''}
4
: 
{name: 'target_tag', value: 'div'}
```

But I need it to be similar to this:

```
{
0 : {
target_tag:'',
animation_status:'',
duration:'',
},
1 : {
target_tag:'',
animation_status:'',
duration:'',
},
...
}
```

Comment: Might be easier to manually serialise your form rather than try to transpose the serializeArray() result.  Can you include the form elements for `.sts_create form` that creates that array?

Comment: @freedomn-m I don't think this idea will work... because the user adds or deletes items to the form through the button, I don't know exactly, maybe it will work :-!
If you have a solution, I would be grateful if you could help

Comment: A different approach may be better, but I think you would need to provide more of the HTML and JS that currently drive the form for people to be able to help with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help? Please see code comments for a bit of info on how this works.

```js
const input_data = [
  {name: 'target_tag', value: 'a'},
  {name: 'animation_status', value: 'animation-1'},
  {name: 'duration', value: ''},
  {name: 'target_tag', value: 'div'},
  {name: 'animation_status', value: 'animation-1'},
  {name: 'duration', value: ''},
];

const collate = (input_data) => {
  const result = [{}];
  
  for(const input_info of input_data) {
    // check to see if the last item in the results array has an entry for the
    // current input name, create a new object at the end of the array if it does
    if(result[result.length - 1].hasOwnProperty(input_info.name))
      result.push({});
    
    // add entry to object at end of result array
    result[result.length - 1][input_info.name] = input_info.value;
  }
  
  // convert result array to object
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(result));
};

console.log(collate(input_data));
```

EDIT: updated `collate` to expect an array rather than an object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that self-serialises to an array of objects, you can then reformat that array in various different ways (included).

As there's no HTML provided, the first assumption/change is that each "item" (group of fields) is itself each contained with another element - in this case:

```
<div class='sts'>
    <input name='..'>
    <input name='..'>
    ...
</div>
```

this also allows for easy "*user adds or deletes items to the form"*.

You can then loop through each wrapper to generate the field outputs and they are then self-contained, rather than a long, flat array that must be broken up.

```js
$("#addmore").click(() =>
  $(".sts").last().after($(".sts").first().clone())
);

$("#generate").click(() => {
  let result = [];
  $(".sts").each((_, sts) => {
    let values = {};
    $(sts).find("input,select").each((_, inp) => {
      values[inp.name] = $(inp).val();
    });
    result.push(values);
  });

  // Array with eech element an object collated from the form
  console.log(result);

  // JSON version of the array, but with no array indicies
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

  // JSON version of the array with indices
  console.log(JSON.stringify($.extend({}, result)));
});
```

```css
.sts::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0.5em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='sts'>
  Tag: 
  <input name='target_tag' value='a'><br /> 
  Status:
  <select name='animation_status'>
    <option selected>animation-1</option>
    <option>animation-2</option>
    <option>animation-3</option>
  </select><br /> 
  Duration:
  <input name='duration'><br />
</div>

<div class='sts'>
  Tag: 
  <input name='target_tag' value='div'><br /> 
  Status:
  <select name='animation_status'>
    <option>animation-1</option>
    <option selected>animation-2</option>
    <option>animation-3</option>
  </select><br /> 
  Duration: 
  <input name='duration'><br />
</div>

<button id='addmore'>add more</button>
<button id='generate'>generate</button>
```

View results in browser console (rather than snippet console)